# Proving the set is compact

Tags: analysis, optimization, solution-verification, proof-explanation, compactness

I have to prove the following set is compact

$$B = \{x\in\mathbb{R}; x + e^x \leq 2022\}$$

Also I have to prove that $\max_{x\in B} x e^x \leq 1011^2$.

**Compactness**

In order to prove $B$ is compact, I have to show it's closed and bounded.

About the closedness, I reasoned as follows: interpreting the writing of the set, I writ $B$ as

$$B = (-\infty, x^*]$$

Where $x^*$ is the value that makes $x + e^x = 2022$.
Since $x\in\mathbb{R}$ I thought we start from $-\infty$.

Then I can prove $B$ is closed reasoning on the complementary: $B^c = \mathbb{R}\backslash B = (x^*, +\infty)$

This is open for it does contains all its internal points. Indeed be $p\in B^c$, I can always find $r>0$ such that $(p-r, p+r)$ contains a point $q$ with $q\in B^c$.

Hence $B^c$ is open and then $(B^c)^c = B$ is closed.

I am having troubles with the boundedness instead... The minus infinity stumbles me.
Any hint?

Also I am having problems in proving the max question.

P.s. the two functions are indeed $x + e^x$ in the first place, and $xe^x$ in the second place, in case one wonders if I wrote it correctly (from professor's sheet).

Comment: $B$ is not compact, though.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I was wondering if the professor wrote it badly. What if it were $$B = \{x\in\mathbb{R}; xe^x < 2022\}$$
That would be bounded, yes? Since at $-\infty$ we have zero...

Comment: Still not compact, because it's unbounded and not closed.

Comment: Both $\{x\in\mathbb{R}; x + e^x \leq 2022\}$ and $\{x\in\mathbb{R}; x e^x \leq 2022\}$ contain all numbers $x < -1$, so that these sets are not bounded.

Comment: @Numb3rs Could it be $\{x\in \mathbb{R}_0^+: x + e^x \leq 2022\}$? This would work.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio What's the error in my proof of $B$ being closed?

Comment: @PierreCarre In the sheet there is written $\mathbb{R}$, but it could be a typo at this point...

Comment: @MartinR I'm having troubles in understanding this. For example the set $A = \{\ln(n)/n\}$ defined in $\mathbb{N} \backslash \{0\}$ is bounded even if it contains all the points to infinity...

Comment: $0 \le \ln(n)/n < 1$, so $A$ does *not* contain arbitrarily large points. But $B$ is a superset of $(-\infty, -1]$.

Comment: @Numb3rs The set $A$ that you mention is not made of the points $n = 1, 2, \cdots$, it is made of their images through the function $\frac 1x \log x$, i.e.
$$
\frac 11 \log 1, \frac 12 \log 2, \frac 13 \log 3, \cdots
$$

Comment: @MartinR Thank you. I still don't get why $(-\infty, x^*]$ is not closed. I mean if we can show that $[0, +\infty)$ is closed, which indeed is, then why isn't closed that too?

Comment: @Numb3rs: $(-\infty, x^*]$ is closed. My comment was about the *boundedness* of your sets $B$.

Comment: @MartinR Oh I know, sorry. I was referring to Giulio Sassatelli's comment, but I asked you because I "met" you a lot over here and I know I can trust you!

Comment: @MartinR Sorry for bothering you, just a final question: how can I prove $$\max_{x\in B} xe^x < 1011^2$$
Considering that $B$ is a bounded and closed set? Like $B = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^+, x+e^x < 2022\}$ or something else like $B = \{x\in\mathbb{R}, \vert x+e^x\vert < 2022\}$

Thank you...

Comment: @Numb3rs: Hint: the inequality between geometric and arithmetic mean: $\sqrt{x e^x} \le \frac 12 (x+e^x)$

Comment: @MartinR Genius. Infinitely thank you!